# What's different about Database as a Value in Datomic vs BiTemporal Indexes in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datomic, temporal, bi-temporal

The [Datomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datomic) database has the concept of '[Database as a Value](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Datomic-Database-Value)'. This means that you can get a [reference to the database](http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html) at a point in time - and query against it.

It appears that [BiTemporal Indexes](https://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/stratio-geospatial-and-bitemporal-search-in-cassandra-with-pluggable-lucene-index) in [Cassandra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra) do almost the same thing.

My question is: **What's different about Database as a Value in Datomic vs BiTemporal Indexes in Cassandra?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two concepts are very similar, in that they allow you to query the database at a specific point in time.  There are a few points that separate them though:

1. Temporal query is built into Datomic from the ground up, whereas it's a plugin to Cassandra.  Also, with Cassandra, you will have to maintain the temporal fields yourself - the plugin from that presentation only helps with querying, not inserts or updates.
2. "Database as a Value" extends beyond point-in-time query.  For example:

   - You can get a database value in a middleware of a web request and passing it along to the following middlewares and handler functions.  This ensures that all queries made during a request are automatically consistent - you can do as many queries as you want against it and never have to worry about doing them inside a read transaction.  You might be able to make something similar to this work using the point-in-time query, but it would be a lot uglier code-wise.
   - You can do "what-if" updates to a database value without having any impact on the actual database.